# bringSubviewToFront don't work

Tags: ios

ClassA :ClassB

in ClassB:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.errorView]
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.errorView];
```

in ClassA:

```
[self.view addSubview:otherView];
```

result:otherView show on errorView
I hope:errorView at front 
What should I do in ClassB ? Thanks.

Comment: try to add on view's window ": [self.view.window addSubview:self.errorView]

Comment: or UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[mainWindow addSubview:self.errorView];

Comment: How r u creating error view

Comment: How about calling `bringSubviewToFront:self.errorView` after calling `[self.view addSubview:otherView]`?